# Swift: Unable to access weak ref to func()

Tags: swift, grand-central-dispatch

I'm getting the following error:

> ~.swift:89:50: 'TreeContainerView?' does not have a member named
>   'updateValues'

..even though 'updateValues' does exist as shown below.

```
class TreeContainerView:UIView {

     override func awakeFromNib() {
        weak var weakSelf:TreeContainerView? = self
        let delayInSeconds:Double = 0.25

        timer = dispatch_source_create(DISPATCH_SOURCE_TYPE_TIMER, 0, 0, dispatch_get_main_queue());     
 ...
        dispatch_source_set_event_handler(timer, weakSelf.updateValues);
        dispatch_resume(timer);
    }

    func updateValues() {

    }
    ...
}
```

However it does compile if I replace 'weakSelf.updateValues' with 'self.updateValues'.

Question: 
1) Is the following the correct Swift version (the ObjC uses a block)?

```
dispatch_source_set_event_handler(timer, weakSelf.updateValues);
```

2) How do I implement a weak reference in Swift (per this context)?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that weakSelf is an optional TreeContainerView. In order to access its methods you have unwrap weak self to access the actual TreeContainerView if it exists like this:

```
dispatch_source_set_event_handler(timer, weakSelf!.updateValues);
```

Comment: However, bear in mind that the *reason* it's optional is because it might be nil, of course, so you probably shouldn't just force-unwrap it and use it anyway...

Comment: That's true. I'd recommend passing a closure that calls that function if it is not nil